# TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, lightning-datatable, screen-flow, flow-screen-component

I have a problem on a datatable with inline edit used in a flow. The edits must saved on the JS array and refresh the table with new values.
When i want to save the edits, i get the error of Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'IPP_RefLog__c'.
I use the code below :

```
async handleLieuSave( event ) {
        const draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
            this.recordsLieux = this.updateRecords(draftValues,this.recordsLieux);
}
updateRecords (drafts, realRecords){
        var data = [...realRecords];
        for( let rec of data){
            let draft = drafts.find(drft => (drft[this.keyField] == rec[this.keyField] && drft.Id === rec.Id));
            console.log('draft:', draft);
            if ( draft != undefined) {
                let fieldNames = Object.keys(draft);
                for(let fn of fieldNames){
                    console.log('before rec[fn]:', rec[fn]);
                    rec[fn] = Object.assign({},draft[fn]);
                    console.log('after draft[fn]:', draft[fn]);
                    console.log('after rec[fn]:', rec[fn]);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log('data:', data);
        return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...` is only a shallow copy; the individual elements of `realRecords` are also write-protected. We can use `{...obj1, ...obj2}` as a type of Object.assign. This reduces your code to just:

```
updateRecords(drafts, realRecords) {
    const fn = (draft, record) => draft[this.keyField] == record[this.keyField] && draft.Id == record.Id;
    return realRecords.map(record => ({ ...record, ...(drafts.find(draft => fn(draft, record)) || {}) }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox it helps me !!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of `Object.assign()` is that it modifies/copies full objects and not just specific fields. Have you tried substituting `rec[fn] = Object.assign({},draft[fn]);` for `rec[fn] = draft[fn];`?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @identigral I read that documentation shortly after I posted. Thanks and apologies.